# jQuery bxSlider autoDirection 'prev' issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, slider, bxslider

I am working on a vertical ticker for a website. i am using bx slider.

Its all set - i need the autoDirection to be set as 'prev' and i need the tickerHover option to be set as well. Using autoDirection brings unwanted speed changes in my ticker. when ever i hover my mouse, it works quite well - the ticker pauses.

But when the mouse is hovered out of the ticker, the ticker sometimes scrolls very quickly or sometimes very slowly.

```
$('#carousel').bxSlider({
    useCSS: false,
    mode:"vertical",
    ticker: true,
    speed: 6000,
    tickerHover:true,
    autoDirection:"prev"
});
```

here is the fiddle: -`http://jsfiddle.net/devilived/z9QdV/2/`

Can anyone point me to how i can set up right.

Comment: Why is there the PHP tag?

Comment: @LightStyle am sorry, i have deleted the php tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue and solved using some CSS3 tricks. I hope it will work for you.

```js
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
useCSS: false,
    mode:"vertical",
    ticker: true,
    speed: 10000,
    tickerHover:true
});
```

```css
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    border: solid #fff 5px;
    left: -5px;
    background: #fff;
}

  .bxsliderWrapper {
    transform: rotate(180deg);    
  }
  
  .bxsliderWrapper li {
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.css">
<div class="bxsliderWrapper">
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_trees.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/me_trees.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_fence.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```